# how to add a stamp (cachet)to a quotation using HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, odoo, qweb

[image]I'm new in odoo and HTML&css, all I want is to add a stamp to my qutation so theu user won't need to put a stamp in every single quotation...can anyone help me and guide me to a road to fix that problem

thanks for your help.

```
    <table class="table3">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:45%;border-style:none;">

                <table style="width:60%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-size:14px;margin-left:4px; margin-right:auto;border: 2px"><br/>Bon pour accord le <br/><br/><br/> <br/><br/><br/>Nom, Qualité et signature ou cachet du client<br/><br/></td> 
                    </tr>


                </table>

            </td>
            <td>
                <table id="t01">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:30%;font-size:12px"><b>Total DA HT</b></td>
                        <td>225,00</td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:30%; font-size:12px"><b>Total TVA</b></td>
                        <td>55.10</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:30%;font-size:12px"><b>Droit de timbre</b></td>
                        <td>0.0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:30%;font-size:12px"><b>Total DA TTC</b></td>
                        <td>350</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>


    <div class="footer">
            <br/><br/>
                  <div style="text-align:center">
<hr style="border: 1px solid #73ad20">

                            <p style="font-family:KacstFarsi; color:green; font-size:9px">N° R.C.: 1003703 -10 B /00/16//N.I.F.: 001016100370377</p>
                            <p style="font-family:KacstFarsi; color:green; font-size:9px">AGB BANQUE RIB: 03200001500720120844Dely-Brahim /N° Article 16500743415</p>


                    <small>
                        <span>Page</span>
                        <span class="page" />
                        /
                        <span class="topage" />
                    </small>
                  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "stamp to your quotation" .. maybe elaborate more with examples ?

Comment: I have an exampel, all I need is to put that signature and stamp in (right,bottom)

Comment: So you need an image(signature and stamp) at the bottom right of your HTML page ?

Comment: yes , (I do have the image with signature in it...),I have no idea how to put it and also, if my quotation needs a second page  the image must be always with that small table in the right

Comment: so can you show the HTML code you have done so far? table etc

Comment: what you see in my code is the second part ( the table in the right and the footer)

Answer (score 0):

You could extend `res.users` with a field for the signature image (`fields.binary`) and extend the settings view (right corner "login" settings). So every user can set his own signature image. Little hint: `res.users` is a bit special. You need to implement that field as user-writeable field ([Odoo example](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/odoo/addons/base/res/res_users.py#L180)). In my example the field is called `sign_image`.

After this you can use this new field in your QWeb report, like:

```xml
<t t-if="o.user_id.sign_image">
    <div t-field="o.user_id.sign_image" t-field-options='{"widget": "image"}'/>
</t>
```

Where `o` is the actual record (quotation) which is printed and `o.user_id` is the salesman on that. If you want to use the user who is printing instead of the salesman use `o.env.user.sign_image`.

Comment: thanks, but I guess this is for version 10 and I'm on version 8